# Numbers vs. Strings: Language fitness challenge

Tags: string, number, code-challenge

*inspired by [thejonymyster's idea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61968948#61968948)*

### Rules

This challenge is about finding languages that are very suitable for one task but quite the opposite in the other. The two tasks share a theme, but Task 1 is designed to be number-oriented while 2 is string-oriented. You can participate in **three categories**:

- **Numbers**: Choose a language, and solve both tasks in it. The language must be specified down to a specific *implementation, version, and flags*, and these *cannot be changed once posted*. Each solution is scored by the code size in bytes; your answer's score is \${T_2}/{T_1}\$ where \$T_1\$ is the score for Task 1 and \$T_2\$ is for Task 2. Higher score is better.
- **Strings**: Same as Numbers, except for scoring. Your answer's score is \${T_1}/{T_2}\$, i.e. the reciprocal of that of Numbers. Higher score is better.
- **Robbers**: Choose an answer X for Numbers or Strings. Come up with a better solution for the worse task for the given language, and post it as a comment. By doing this, you gain (effectively steal) X's score lost. Higher total score is better.

  - Example: Let's assume a Numbers post with 4B in task 1 and 9B in task 2. If you golf task 2 down to 7B, the answer's score is reduced from 9/4 to 7/4, and you get 2/4 = 0.5 points.

You will naturally participate in Numbers if your solution to Task 2 is longer than Task 1, and in Strings otherwise. However, you may *not* switch the category of an answer already posted, even if the golfing attempts result in the score less than 1.

Everyone is free to give golfing suggestions to existing answers, but the only ones that *reduce* the answer's score count as robbers.

Once the challenge is inactive for **1 week**, the winners of each category will be decided as follows:

- **Numbers** and **Strings**: the highest scoring answer in each category wins.
- **Robbers**: the participant with the highest total stolen score wins.

### Task 1: Number thickness

Given a positive integer \$n\$ and integer base \$b \ge 2\$, compute the thickness of \$n\$ in base \$b\$. For base 2, the values are [A274036](http://oeis.org/A274036). The thickness is computed as follows: if the inputs are \$n = 22\$ and \$b = 2\$,

- Convert \$n\$ to base-\$b\$ digits: \$10110_2\$
- Treat it as a polynomial: \$B_n(x) = 1x^4 + 0x^3 + 1x^2 + 1x^1 + 0x^0\$
- Compute its square: \$B_n(x)^2 = x^8 + 2x^6 + 2x^5 + x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2\$
- Take the highest coefficient: 2.

Therefore, the thickness of 22 in base 2 is 2.

**Test cases**

```
22, 2 -> 2
8, 2 -> 1
15, 2 -> 4
100, 3 -> 6
12345, 10 -> 46
```

### Task 2: String thickness

Given a nonempty string \$s\$ consisting of uppercase letters, compute the string thickness of \$s\$. It is calculated as follows: if the input is `ABAAB`,

- For each length-2 substring of \$s\$, replace all non-overlapping appearances of it with \$s\$.

  - `AB -> ABAAB`: `ABAABAABAAB`
  - `BA -> ABAAB`: `AABAABAABAABAABAABAB`
  - `AA -> ABAAB`: `ABAABBABAABBABAABBABAABBABAABBABAABBAB`
  - `AB -> ABAAB`: `ABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAAB`
- Count how many times \$s\$ appears as non-overlapping substrings of the result.

```
ABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAABAABAABBABAAB
11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999 aaaaa bbbbb ccccc ddddd
```

The string thickness of `ABAAB` is 13.

For this task, taking the input string as a list of chars or a list of codepoints is allowed.

**Test cases**

```
ABAAB -> 13
AB -> 1
XXYY -> 2
ARRAY -> 3
NUMBER -> 5
PQRRQP -> 6
XYXZYX -> 21
```

### Example submission

```
# Numbers, Python 3.10, score 109 / 54 = 2.0185

## Task 1, 54 bytes

    <insert code here><insert code here><insert code here>

## Task 2, 109 bytes

    <insert code here><insert code here><insert code here>
    <insert code here><insert code here><insert code here>
```

Comment: @Steffan Tagging as [tag:code-golf] would imply that the winning criterion is "shortest code wins".

Comment: I don't have the time to attempt it now, but a sed strings answer could be a strong contender.

Comment: This challenge made me realize a lot of (golfing) languages lack a `replace` builtin.. :/

Comment: Could we get some test cases?

Answer (score 7):

## Strings, [Python 3.8.10](https://www.python.org/), score 83 / 65 = 1.2769

### Task 1, 83 bytes

*-7 bytes from @xnor **(+7/65)***

```py
lambda n,b:max(sum(n//b**i%b*(n*b**i//b**k%b)for i in range(n))for k in range(n+1))
```

[Attempt this Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwWI_25ilpSVpuhY3g3MSc5NSEhXydJKschMrNIpLczXy9PWTtLQyVZO0NPK0QCwwP1s1STMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPEyySjSSibaipCTF6fUFRZl6Jhp-GkZGOghFMdMECCA0A)

### Task 2, 65 bytes

*-1 byte from @Steffan*

```py
s=t=p=input()
for c in s:t=t.replace(p+c,s);p=c
print(t.count(s))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3HYttS2wLbDPzCkpLNDS50vKLFJIVMvMUiq1KbEv0ilILchKTUzUKtJN1ijWtC2yTuQqKMvNKNEr0kvNLgXSxpibEoAUwytHJ0dEJwgEA)

Comment: Replace `t=t.replace(p+(p:=c),s)` with `t=t.replace(p+c,s);p=c` for -1 byte / -0.02097 score

Comment: @Steffan I think you mean +0.02097 score, right?

Comment: Yes. (filler) (filler)

Comment: It's much more boring, but I think [this works for 84 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ8kqN7FCo7g0VyNPXz9JSytTNUkLytTI1s3UVE3STMsvUshUyMxTKErMS0/VyNY21ASLZSPE8kBi/wuKMvNKNNI0jIx0jIBcAA) on task 1.

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##TchBCoAgEEDRq7gJRgsi20TQTdo4lCXmJGZQp7dy1e6/7@@47tR2PiQ9jGlTDifFqMLeqQuO0wHVNQphChRA4qtsWyDXe2CGGWJB0TID8Xzs75QN58kHQxE0SFnJlw8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") with a small tweak

Comment: -1: `n*b**i//b**k` -> `n//b**(k-i)`

Answer (score 6):

## Numbers, [Factor](https://factorcode.org) 0.99 Build #1889 + `math.extras math.polynomials`, score 66 / 53 = 1.2453

### Task 1, 53 bytes

```factor
[ '[ [ _ /mod , ] until-zero ] f make 2 p^ supremum ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JYw9CsJAFIT7nGI6GxNhQRA9gNjYiDYhyhLfYsj-xN23YLyKTRpzp9zG4DYzzAfzfUYla3Z-mC7n0-G436Ilb0lD-R5G8uMfRed0b51ppA4zaClRerGXAYGekWxNAZ0n5r7zjWXsskwIiG9klW-mdYlFiRI3rIy7Y4kK0XKj8zd5Nw-VtALdFSHOHhMNqnQea6k1ijSGIfUP)

### Task 2, 66 bytes

```factor
[| s | s s s 2 clump [ <regexp> s re-replace ] each count-subseq ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU6xCsIwFNz9iqN7OziJitAu4uIiupQOMbzWYkziSwIV_BOXLvaf-je2ZJDjeHc33LvPUAvpDffj5Xw6HPdrKCOFcmjYBNvqBkwNdRaWyfuX5VZ7OHoG0pLcX2XUeRYOd2JNCpvFIsmLPC-Sb_B1uhqL8g2HmTOWkCo8LEpsY_1uCplSJquEJFQgIW-QJmifunCd3qCKTcO0TiGLpu_j_QE)

I didn't expect Factor to score particularly well here since it's pretty consistent in most areas. Now if it were iterative vs. recursive, you might see Factor reigning supreme...

P.S. I was able to knock 12 bytes off one of the answers after posting, so FML.

Answer (score 5):

## Numbers, [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr) 2.13.4, score 77 / 37 = 2.0811

### Task 1, 37 bytes

```
n->b->vecmax(Vec(Pol(digits(n,b))^2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN1XzdO2SdO3KUpNzEys0wlKTNQLyczRSMtMzS4o18nSSNDXjjDQ1IYrXFxRl5pVopGkYGWlqwEUXLIDQAA)

PARI/GP has a built-in polynomial type.

### Task 2,  77 bytes

```
s->u=strjoin;v=strsplit;for(i=2,#t=s,t=u(v(t,u(Vec(s)[i-1..i])),s));#v(t,s)-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHidAXbpaUlaboWN32Lde1KbYtLirLyM_Osy0Cs4oKczBLrtPwijUxbIx3lEttinRLbUo0yjRKdUo2w1GSNYs3oTF1DPb3MWE1NnWJNTWtlkFyxpq4hxNCNBUWZeSUa6RpKjk6Ojk5KmpoQ8QULIDQA)

PARI/GP has only two string-manipulation built-ins: `strjoin` and `strsplit`. We can do string search-and-replace by `strjoin(strsplit(s,a),b)`.

Answer (score 3):

## Numbers, [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) 13.1.0, score <s>1.26315</s> 1.47826

+0.2151 score thanks to att!

### Task 1, <s>57</s> 46 bytes

```
Max@ListConvolve[#,#,{1,-1},0]&@*IntegerDigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexwsEns7jEOT@vLD@nLDVaWUdZp9pQR9ewVscgVs1ByzOvJDU9tcglMz2zpPh/QFFmXomCg0JatJGRjlHsfwA)

-11 bytes thanks to att

### Task 2, <s>72</s> 68 bytes

```
Fold[StringReplace,x=#,#->x&/@StringPartition[x,2,1]]~StringCount~x&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y0/JyU6uKQoMy89KLUgJzE5VafCVllHWdeuQk3fASIRkFhUklmSmZ8XXaFjpGMYG1sHEXfOL80rqatQ@x8A5JUoOCikAbGSo5Ojo5PSfwA)

-4 bytes thanks to att

Comment: [-5 bytes task 1](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexwsEns7jEOT@vLD@nLDVaWUdZp9pQR9ewVscgVs1ByzOvJDU9tcglMz2zpPh/QFFmXomCg0JatJGRjlHsfwA) (→ 1.56522) and [-4 bytes task 2](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y0/JyU6uKQoMy89KLUgJzE5VafCVllHWdeuQk3fASIRkFhUklmSmZ8XXaFjpGMYG1sHEXfOL80rqatQ@x8A5JUoOCikAbGSo5Ojo5PSfwA) (-0.08696 → 1.47826)

Comment: Oops, forgot to change: -11, not -5 on task 1. The -5 used `O` to get the coefficient list.

Answer (score 3):

## Strings, [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score 15/9 = 1.666...

### Task 1, 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
вDδ*εā_«NFÁ]øOà
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//9CyRM60Ks61xIFfwqtORsOBXcO4T8Og//8yCjIy)

### Task 2, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ü2I.:I¡g<
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8B4jTz0rz0ML023@/3d0cnR0AgA)

05AB1E lacks any polynomial builtins, and unfortunately also a matrix-diagonals builtin. So all things considering, the Numbers Task 1 isn't too long, if I say so myself.

No doubt someone still finds something to golf, since that's usually the case with my answers. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Numbers, [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) 2.17.1, score 9/8 = 1.125

Vyxal doesn't do very well for this challenge.

### Task 1, 8 bytes

```
τ:v*ÞḋṠG
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLPhDp2KsOe4biL4bmgRyIsIiIsIjJcbjIyIl0=)

### Task 2, 9 bytes

```
2l(n?V)$O
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIybChuP1YpJE8iLCIiLCJBQkFBQiJd)

Comment: Vyxal `G`? Would make your score 10/7

Answer (score 2):

## Numbers, [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 13/5 = 2.6

### Task 1, 5 bytes

```
bæc`Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p8LLkhIc7G/7//29k9N8IAA)

### Task 2, 13 bytes

```
ṡ2œṣj³ɗƒœṣ¹L’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoVGRyc/3Lk469Dmk9OPTQKzD@30edQw8////45Ojo5OAA)

It's common knowledge that Jelly is not good with strings, but this is exceptionally awkward for its builtin set with some chaining issues on top. Maybe I'll get robbed?

Answer (score 2):

## Numbers, J 806, Score 48 / 23 = 2.08696

### Task 1, 23 bytes

```
[:>./[:+//.@:(*/)~#.inv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63s9PSjrbT19fUcrDS09DXrlPUy88r@a3JxpSZn5CsYKaQpGBn9BwA)

### Task 2, 48 bytes

```
#%~;&''(]-&#rplc~)[:;<rplc~&.>/@|.@,<<"1@,.~2<\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYtNC4JAFEX3/oqn0jwHZp4fQeA4imPUSlq0TSGQJCIoWtf89UlcRBC0uHA599yLy32V9itf5YheQDhCqQBBQAJqiiRY79utCxe2YIhRL1n4uF8Hyw@q0HNjVMX1k2qhdZDWgmymu95xb9cQ/JdmRX/RD5x@UVJRJm3cJQKNQbYhfoyKWCjNX7Pzs3un4XyDdAkljICmMaZB9wY)

Strings might have an open window or two for an enterprising robber...

Comment: Quick [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##fYvLCsIwFET3/YrbCr0JpLcPQWiSlqaiK3Hh1gaEYhERFNc2vx5LFyIILgaGM2euvgxlblehLBGDiHCASgKCgAzklIRgfdhtPVMjcWaTePF83HrHj1LpucVUp82LGqF1lDeCXKE763mwbwn@S7Oiv@gHTj@W1VQkLu0ygcZgvCF@YioVUvNxdn724Nxf7pAvoYIB0LTGtOjf) for Task 2: avoid division by replacing with `(;}.)` instead of `;&''`.

Comment: Thanks bubbler.... So, do I change it or am I being robbed?

Answer (score 2):

## Numbers, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), score 23 / 19 = 1.21

### Task 1, 19 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＩ⌈↨Ｘ↨↨θη×θη²×θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ8B5AcUZeaVaDgnFpdo@CZWZOaW5mo4JRanagTklwNVgJlgolBHIUNTRyEkMze1GMIB8ozQRIDA@v9/IyMuo/@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on @dingledooper's Python answer but using Charcoal's base conversion builtins to simplify the process.

### Task 2, 23 bytes

```
ＳηＦＥΦθκ⁺§θκι≔⪫⪪ηιθηＩ№ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxNCsIwEIX3niLLCcQTdJUKQgWh0BOEWpvBYfI3EW8fU8HFe4v38b7Vu7wGR61NHKsskpF38Ho4PUNWcHcRrkiyZUhGvbRRM9UCViZ@bJ//hlprZUvBneEWkGGJhAL@IEalnkM4d7XAxZVeofKPp/4cWrOjtWM7v@kL) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal struggles to extract overlapping substrings, and like PARI/GP, has to use both Split and Join to perform string replacement. It does at least have a convenient way to refer to the same string input twice.

Answer (score 2):

## Strings, [Go](https://go.dev) 1.19.1, score <s>177 / 162 = 1.09259</s> 176 / 121 = 1.41322

### Task 1: <s>177</s> 176 bytes

```go
func n(n,b int)int{c,m:=[]int{},-1
for n>0{c=append(c,n%b)
n/=b}
s:=make([]int,len(c)*2)
for i,x:=range c{for j,y:=range c{s[i+j]+=x*y}}
for _,n:=range s{if m<n{m=n}}
return m}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9NasMwEIXX0SmGQIOUKP3xqpgqZ8g-hCCrUlASjY0sQ4LQSboxhe5zg54jt6nspnQxzPDeG_jex-e-7r8bqY5yr8FJi4RY19Q-ACWTqXFhSthXF8zy9XY1HSpAirwCi4HliYq7Umy2w5n48oWY2gOunqMSsmk0vlPF8aFiBJ9ElUhbCiePmo4P_KSRKjYv2Phl-bkUXmLGUHEQDvzyL7QbuzhsF-I8v6Q05ncc_-w2WgPuDaMTmF2vQ-cRXLpzz0buoRtlEMkkl3pc-0xwyl1oUXAoGCP3dN__7h8)

- -1 by @Steffan

### Task 2: <s>162</s> 121 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func s(s string)int{p,t:=s,s
for _,c:=range s{q:=string(c);t=ReplaceAll(t,p+q,s);p=q}
return Count(t,s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BCsIwEEXX5hQhqwRj11LJovUC4gUkhLYU2yTNTBZSehI3RfAS3sTbGNuuBt58_n_PV-Pmj9fmrpuK9rq1hLS9dwEpq3tk74j14fh9rCxjgKG1DTBSR2socKArEa3F0UvMFUggtQv0Jk2ugrapFsYh8SXHjTihula-06Yquo6j9PtBgjh5NUwkVBiDpWcXLaYXiGkT4Mve348LOpJdcssuqRA7y4GzoiyKkglBtvw8r_cH)

- -41 by @Steffan

Comment: [121](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BCsIwEEXX5hQhqwRj11LJovUC4gUkhLYU2yTNTBZSehI3RfAS3sTbGNuuBt58_n_PV-Pmj9fmrpuK9rq1hLS9dwEpq3tk74j14fh9rCxjgKG1DTBSR2socKArEa3F0UvMFUggtQv0Jk2ugrapFsYh8SXHjTihula-06Yquo6j9PtBgjh5NUwkVBiDpWcXLaYXiGkT4Mve348LOpJdcssuqRA7y4GzoiyKkglBtvw8r_cH) for the second one

Comment: for the first one, you can remove the newline after `func n(n,b int)int{`

Answer (score 1):

## Numbers, [Pyxplot](http://pyxplot.org.uk) 0.8.4, score 188/99 = 1.8990

### Task 1, 99 bytes

```
su N(n,b){m=0
fo j=0ton{s=0
fo i=0ton{f='floor(n/b*'
s=s+@f*i)%b*@f*j*b**i)%b
}
m=max(m,s)
}
pr m
}
```

The algorithm is the same as in @dingledooper's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252063/92901).

### Task 2, 188 bytes

```
su S(s){t=s
L='strlen'
r='strrange'
fo i=2to@L(s){j=0
c=0
while j<@L(t){if strcmp(@r(t,j,j+2),@r(s,i-2,i)){j=j+1
}else{t='%s%s%s'%(@r(t,0,j),s,@r(t,j+2,@L(t)));j=j+@L(s);c=c+1
}
}
}
pr c
}
```

Pyxplot has a search-and-replace operator (`=~`) but it only works with literal text and so is not of use here. There are only five string manipulation functions (two of which perform case conversions). The three used here are `strcmp`, which performs lexicographical comparison; `strlen`, which returns the length; and `strrange`, which returns a slice.

---

<sup>There is no online interpreter. To install Pyxplot 0.8.4 on an up-to-date system, you need to add `-fgnu89-inline` to the compile flags in line 44 of `Makefile.skel`. You might also need to change `python` to `python2` or `python2.X` in lines 97, 180, and 183.</sup>